# pdo mysql fallback charset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried for a google search on `mysql fallback charset` but did not find any related topic or maybe I am using the wrong keywords....

I wanted to support `utf8mb4` whenever it is possible, but I dont know a proper way of doing a proper fallback for unsupported charset. so currently I am using this to create my PDO instance,

```
$this->dbh = new \PDO ($dsn, $databaseConfig["user"], $databaseConfig["pw"]);
$this->dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$charset = $this->dbh->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION) >= "5.5.0" ? "utf8mb4" : "utf8";
$this->dbh->exec("set names $charset");
```

This will fallback to `utf8` by manually setting a default, but is there a proper way for fallback charset on default in PDO/mysql?? and if it is possible, what will be the default charset choice by PDO/mysql??

Comment: what does your `$dsn` string look like? I would suggest you set it there, instead of looking it up every time.

Comment: @cmorrissey i was trying to support under 5.3.6 so i didnt put it there :(

Comment: what I am saying is that you want it to be a one time check, so you may need an installer script, a read me, something so its set in your `$databaseConfig`

Comment: @cmorrissey i have no experience with installer script but will now take a look of it,  thanks for the recommandation :)